# JavaScript JQuery setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and JQuery and I was trying to exercise something

```
var activetab = 0;

$("li").click(function () {
  $("#tabs-"+activetab).hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
   $("li").eq(activetab).css('background-color','white');
  var index = $("li").index(this);
  $("span").text(index);
  $("li").eq(index).css('background-color','red');
    $("#tabs-"+index).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000); 
  activetab = index;
});
```

Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6WC4J/

The problem is I'd like the show method to fire up after some time such that when the previous element will be hidden then the new one will show up,
tried using setTimeout but didn't work, any ideas?

Thanks Overall

Comment: You can pass a *complete* callback to `.hide`. Please have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/hide/.

Comment: That's actually what I thought right now, gonna try this and post some updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `complete` callback of the [`.hide()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) method to fire the `.show()` animation.

```
$("#tabs-" + activetab).hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
}, 1000, function(){
    $("#tabs-" + index).show("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 1000);
    activetab = index;
});
```

This way you don't need to use a `setTimeout` and the synchronization is seamless.

[See it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZuQkL/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use callbacks:

```
 $("#tabs-" + activetab).hide("slide", {
    direction: "left"
 }, 1000, function(){
     // this will be called after the element is completely hidden.
 });
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: I believe you wanted to link to the [jQuery UI's `.hide()` documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/hide/) instead. Notice, jQuery's `.hide()` doesn't provide the same functionality